# Testing .NET Core Controller View Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In .NET Core we have a controller action that's calling a ViewComponent which has a dependency injection, following the pattern in the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

If we have a controller action that returns a rendered view like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IToDoContext _todoContext;
    public MyController(IToDoContext todoContext)
    {
        _todoContext = todoContext;
    }

    public IActionResult IndexVC()
    {
        return ViewComponent("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 3, isDone = false });
    }
}
```

And a ViewComponent that has a dependency injection like this:

```
public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ToDoContext db;

    public PriorityListViewComponent(ToDoContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
    {
        var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
        return View(items);
    }
    private Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
    {
        return db.ToDo.Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone && x.Priority <= maxPriority).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

How would we inject the ToDoContext into the ViewComponent in the controller action unit test? So far, the result.Model is always null because there doesn't seem to be a way to inject the ToDoContext db into the Controller and then into the ViewComponent.

```
[Fact]
public void Should_return_viewcomponent()
{
    var mockToDoContext = new Mock<IToDoContext>();
    mockToDoContext.Setup(m => m.Get()).ReturnsAsync(new ToDoContext());

    var sut = new MyController(mockToDoContext.Object);

    var result = sut.PriorityListViewComponent("myparams") as ViewComponentResult;
    // ToDoContext db is never set, so the result.Model is always null
}
```

Comment: It's been over 4 years since this question was asked and there still isn't much information available about testing view components. There is a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51645687/2615878 with currently one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I think that Microsoft example was wrong.  Once I changed the View Component to a View and moved the data fetch from the View Component code behind and into the Controller, then everything became easy to test and implement Bad Request logic, and so on.  Just remember to move the View Component out of the View Component directory and set layout to null in the view.

The controller should look more like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IToDoContext _db;
    public MyController(IToDoContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexVC("PriorityList", new { maxPriority, isDone = false })
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(maxPriority))
                return BadRequest($"maxPriority cannot be empty");

            var model = await InvokeAsync(maxPriority, isDone);

            if (model == null)
            {
                return BadRequest($"model not found");
            }

            return View(model);
        }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
            return View(items);
        }
        private Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            return _db.ToDo.Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone &&
                                 x.Priority <= maxPriority).ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

And the unit test would look like:

```
[Fact]
public void Should_return_viewcomponent()
{
    var mockToDoContext = new Mock<IToDoContext>();
    mockToDoContext.Setup(m => m.Get())
        .ReturnsAsync(new ToDoContext());

    var sut = new MyController(mockToDoContext.Object);

    var result = await sut.PriorityList("myparams") as ViewResult;
    result.Model.ShouldNotBeNull();
    var resultModel = result.Model as PriorityListModel;
    resultModel.ShouldNotBeNull();
    resultModel.Thing.ShouldBe("whatever");
}
```

The Bad Request unit test would look like this (notice the BadRequestObjectResult):

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_return_bad_request_if_result_not_found()
{
    var mockToDoContext = new Mock<IToDoContext>();
    mockToDoContext.Setup(m => m.Get())
        .ReturnsAsync(null);

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

    var sut = new MyController(mockToDoContext.Object)
    {
        ControllerContext = new ControllerContext { HttpContext = httpContext }
    };
    var result = await sut.PriorityList("myparams") as BadRequestObjectResult;

    result.ShouldNotBeNull();
    result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(400);
    result.Value.ShouldBe("model not found");
}
```