# Wanting to Create a Unit Test for ViewComponent in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

One of the big advertised benefits of ViewComponents vs partial pages in ASP.NET Core 2.1 is suppose to be that they are very easy to test.  I can't find any examples in the docs for how I would actually test one.

My ViewComponent takes an IConfiguration in it's constructor so I can inject AppSetting values.  It's executed with a couple parameters that are passed in with Invoke.  I'm assuming I want to somehow test the model that is returned to the view and make sure it is what I expect (based on AppSettings and those two parameters).

[EDIT]
Here is a sample simple ViewComponent that uses the configuration service and has a parameter passed into invoke.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace WebApp.Pages.Components.RatingControl
{

    public class MyModel
    {
        public string MyVal1 { get; set; }
        public string MyVal2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewData
    {
        public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }
        public string Param1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class SimpleViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly MyModel _myModel;

        public SimpleViewComponent(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _myModel = new MyModel
            {
                MyVal1 = config["myVal1"],
                MyVal2 = config["myVal2"],
            };
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string param1)
        {
            var myViewData = new MyViewData
            {
                MyModel = _myModel,
                Param1 = param1
            };

            return View(myViewData);
        }

    }
}
```

Maybe it's obvious but I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Provide an example of the component you want to test and how you have tried to test it so far in a [mcve]

Comment: The sour repo would tests you can use as an example but they would be targeting the specific functionalities of the component. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Test/ViewComponentTests.cs

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, thanks for the example but I don't see a way to pass a Configuration (IConfiguration) into the viewcomponent as part of the test in the list shown.

Answer (score 2):

Should really not pass `IConfiguration` as a dependency. You already have a model that you populate so you can take advantage of the binding capabilities of the configuration framework and explicitly inject the populated model from configuration at startup..

So assuming your *appsetting.json* file

```
{
  ...

  "myval1": "value1",
  "myval2": "value2",

  ...
}
```

and the existing `MyModel`, you can bind the object graph at start up from configuration as suggested practice from documentation.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

Configuration = builder.Build();

var myModel = new MyModel();
Configuration.Bind(myModel);
```

You would then register the model app settings with the service collection

```
services.AddSingleton(myModel);
```

since view components are initialized with dependency injection by the framework.

Now there is really no need to be injecting `IConfiguration` into the view component as the model can be injected as an explicit dependency

```
public class SimpleViewComponent : ViewComponent {
    private readonly MyModel model;

    public SimpleViewComponent(MyModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string param1) {
        var myViewData = new MyViewData {
            MyModel = model,
            Param1 = param1
        };
        return View(myViewData);
    }
}
```

All this will make unit testing the view component in isolation rather easy as initializing a fake instance of the model is a simple matter.

```
//Arrange
var model = new MyModel {
    MyVal1 = "test1",
    MyVal2 = "test2",
}

var viewComponent = new SimpleViewComponent(model);
var param1 = "param1";

//Act
var result = viewComponent.Invoke(param1);

//Assert
result.Should().NotBeNull();
result.ViewData.Model
    .Should().NotBeNull()
    .And.BeOfType<MyViewData>();
//...other assertions
```

Comment: In Core 2.1, they've changed to use CreateWebHostBuilder so your example does not work anymore. Also, are you suggesting never use construction injection? My trivial example, not something that covers all my cases. IConfiguration is just one example. I prefer not to loose construction injection for everything I want to test.

Comment: @Pete you are confusing integration testing and unit testing. Also I never suggested not to use constructor injection. I suggested not to inject `IConfiguration` and use explicit dependency principle.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. How would you test with construction injection? IConfiguration specifically? I don't believe that would be integration testing as the values coming in the constructor change the behavior of the component.

Comment: @Pete I've already shown in my answer how to test it. the model is being injected into the component's constructor. There is no need to couple the component to `IConfiguration`

Comment: respectfully, no you have not. I’m looking for help on how to unit test a view component that has IConfiguration or any other service injected into the constructor.  Not a simple model passed in as a constructor parameter. I’m not asking for an opinion on whether that is a good idea or not.  Here on Microsoft’s curated blog is that exact example but with no test (which is what I’m looking for).  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dariuszporowski/tip-of-the-week-how-to-access-configuration-from-controller-in-asp-net-core-2-0/